# Javascript word boundary unicode space issue

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I want to write a regex pattern that matches for full words or phrases even if they have unicode chars to wrap them with some html code. So I use this pattern:

```
var pattern=new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+phrase+'(?=\\s|$)', "gi");
```

It works perfectly even on multi-word phrases expect for one issue. If the phrase isn't the start of the string, it matches with the space before the word. So after I wrap it I'll lose that space. I only want to wrap the phrase variable and not the spaces.

For example:

```
var string="This is a nice sentence.";
var phrase="is a nice";
/*OUTPUT: Thisis a nicesentence*//*HTML OUTPUT: This<span>is a nice</span>sentence*/
/*What I want: This <span>is a nice</span> sentence*/
```

Of course this pattern could work:

```
var pattern=new RegExp(phrase, "gi");
```

But I'm not looking for those strings that are substrings of another.

Is it possible to solve my issue with a better regex pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write back what you [captured](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in group 1:

```
output = string.replace(pattern, '$1<span>' + phrase + '</span>');
```

If you are not using `replace` but `match` or `exec` and do the replacement manually, you can still access the capturing group in the returned array and insert the space or empty string before your `span`.

By the way, if you capture the phrase as well, you don't need any string concatenation in the replacement:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('(^|\\s)('+phrase+')(?=\\s|$)', "gi");
output = string.replace(pattern, '$1<span>$2</span>');
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks man, it works perfectly. I've struggled with this for days.